# What is the difference between $\partial^2/\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}^2$ and $\partial^2/\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}^T$?

Tags: fisher-information, hessian

I am reading the paper *Efficient Computation of the Fisher Information Matrix in the EM Algorithm* (Meng & Spall) and am unsure what the difference (if any) there is between the notation $\partial^2/\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}^2$ and $\partial^2/\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}^T$ as seen in the screenshot below.  I am comfortable with the fact that $\partial^2/\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}^T$ leads to a matrix of all partial derivatives of order two, that is,
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}^T}f(\boldsymbol\theta)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial_{\theta_1}^2 & \partial_{\theta_1}\partial_{\theta_2} & \cdots & \partial_{\theta_1}\partial_{\theta_n} \\
\partial_{\theta_2}\partial_{\theta_1} & \partial_{\theta_2}^2 & &\vdots\\
\vdots &  & \ddots \\
\partial_{\theta_n}\partial_{\theta_1} & & &\partial_{\theta_n}^2\\
\end{pmatrix}f(\boldsymbol\theta).
$$
But what does $\partial^2/\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}^2$ and $\partial^2/\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}^\ast$, c.f. the *first* starred equation $(\mathbf I_{\text{Oakes}})$, mean?

Should these read $\partial^2/\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}^2=\partial^2/\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}^T$ and $\partial^2/\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}^\ast=\partial^2/\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}(\partial{\boldsymbol\theta}^\ast)^T$?

---

[image]

Comment: @Zhanxiong Sorry, your comment made me realize I had starred two equations.  I was only referring to the first starred equation.

Comment: I believe it is a typo, it should be $\partial^2/\partial \theta\partial\theta^T$ in the first star.  The second star doesn't involve second-order partial derivative anyway, right? But it is possible that the author of [16] used a different notation (though not conventional) to denote the matrix as in $\partial^2/\partial \theta\partial\theta^T$ (which can be inferred from the second term in the first star) -- he just dropped the transpose operator in all cases.